# Find source of Google My Business API request

Tags: google-my-business-api

We are setting up Google My Business using the following oauth instructions.

https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/notification-setup

However, there seems to be a process somewhere that keeps changing the settings and sending the notifications to a different pub/sub topic.  So basically it appears to be making a PUT request to :

[https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/{accountId}/notifications](https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/%7BaccountId%7D/notifications)

Is there a way to determine the source of the request ? There does not seem to be any instructions on how to access Google My Business API audit logs.

Comment: Hi user1591178, did my answer help you resolve your issue? If so, please mark it as correct, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should check who else has access to that location group, ideally through the GMB UI as that can give you an e-mail address hint:

[image: GMB location group details]